# JFileChooser to select the input file java.util.InputMismatchException error

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, file-io, console

In my program I'm trying to do Use JFileChooser to select the input file and display output in colsole. if I choose grade.txt file in that file I have different grades like:

```
20 98.83 40.05 0.97 9.77 87.73 87.80 99.15 94.77 41.39
```

Output look like:

```
Student 1 score is 98.83 and grade is A
Student 2 score is 40.05 and grade is F
Student 3 score is 0.97 and grade is F
```

when I tried to run my program I got Exception in thread "main"

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Homework10.A.main(A.java:23)
```

how can I fix this error?

```
public class A {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

     Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(".");
        int jfcUserOption = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (jfcUserOption == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File chosenFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();

        Scanner input = new Scanner( chosenFile ); 

        while(input.hasNext()){
            int n = input.nextInt();
            int bestScore = 0;
            int[] score = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
           score[i] = input.nextInt();
           if (bestScore < score[i]) {
            bestScore = score[i];
           }
          }



          char grade;
          for (int i = 1; i < score.length; i++) {
           if (score[i] >= bestScore - 10)
            grade = 'A';
           else if (score[i] >= bestScore - 20)
            grade = 'B';
           else if (score[i] >= bestScore - 30)
            grade = 'C';
           else if (score[i] >= bestScore - 40)
            grade = 'D';
           else
            grade = 'F';

           System.out.println("Student " + i +" score is " + score[i] +" and grade is " + grade);
          }

         }

 }
}
}
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Also looks like your score is a double not an int

Comment: @jens I have update error